# Scrape current weather data in R

Tags: r, web-scraping, weather, tidy

I'm trying to scrape weather data from intellecast.com. I can break down and tidy some of the data with the following code but it's not perfect, I can't think of a way to consolidate it in a efficient way. Basically I need to create a vector or table so I can manage the information.

```
# Scrape Weather Data

games.URL.stem = "http://www.intellicast.com/Local/Weather.aspx?location=USMD9906"
weat = readHTMLTable(games.URL.stem)
weat <- weat[[1]]
weat
#check factors 
str(weat)
weat$V1
### isolate and tidy data
WW <- gsub("\r\n","",weat$V1)
WW
WW <- WW[1]
WW
WW <- gsub("        "," ",WW)
WW
WW <- gsub("     "," ",WW)
WW
WW <- gsub("        "," ",WW)
WW
WW <- gsub("Report Text:.*$","",WW)
WW
```

Comment: That site has a lot of elements on that page. Which specific part are you interested in? Is there an API you can use, usually that makes the job much easier. Why not use something like http://www.wunderground.com/weather/api which will return an xml or JSON data which you can use appropriate R package to parse and use directly. You can get started with a free key.

Comment: Or you can go with this as well http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=landover,us